# NodeJs/MySQL Use a variable in where clause condition

Tags: mysql, node.js, where-clause

i want to use a variable in my Where clause like this :

```
con.query("SELECT * FROM vehicules WHERE "myvariable"=?",myothervariable,function (err, result)
    {
// some code
    });
```

it don't seems to work . is that even possible ?

> EDIT

When i try this

```
con.query("SELECT * FROM vehicules WHERE 'myvariable'=?",myothervariable,function (err, result)
```

i got this as output

```
SELECT * FROM vehicules WHERE 'Modele'='X5'
```

Modele is my right column  name but how can i remove the ' '  ?

Comment: what lib do you use with mysql?

Comment: @IuriiDrozdov "mysql" is the lib's name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it's possible indeed.

```
db.query("SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE ??=?",[your_column_name,your_var_from_your_code],function(error,results){.......})
```

And if you want to use multiple statements, go for :

```
db.query("SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE ??=? AND ??=?",[column_name_1,code_var_1,column_name_2,code_var2],function(error,results){...})
```

This should theoretically work, I haven't the time to actually test it.

Comment: Not working , when i do like this it show me this error : field your_var  unknow

Comment: Replace it with your real table column name, I placed random placeholders.. *both your_column_name and your_var_from_your_code are placeholders*, change them both.

Comment: But my column name is a variable , i do this query dynamically whit a dropdown list value .

Comment: I've edited my answer, you should clarify your question just a bit, we misunderstood you. Use double question marks (??) for identifiers and one(?) for values.

Comment: Thanks Working ! how could i make it work if i replace WHERE ??=? with WHERE like ??=?  with contains (??=%?% don't work)

Comment: Try this: `".... LIKE ??=", "%" + ? + "%"` Is it escaping your percentage signs or ? And please accept the answer beforehand as it does resolve the issue stated in the question. I'll try to assist further.

Comment: Unexepected token "?"  : "SELECT * FROM vehicules WHERE LIKE ??=", "%" + ? + "% AND FK_Entreprises=?"

Comment: Put the quotation marks around the question mark as well, my bad, forgot to put them.

Comment: You mean like this ? LIKE ??=", "%" + "?" + "%" still not working  output: this._callback.apply is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
con.query("SELECT * FROM vehicules WHERE ?",{myvariable: myothervariable},function (err, result)
    {
// some code
    });
```

Comment: Not working , field myvariable unknow (it's not taking my variable value but variable name)